# How do I write a stored procedure which adds a column to a ref cursor from another stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure, `GetRegions`, which fetches some columns into a cursor like so:

```
OPEN out_cur FOR
    SELECT id, name, ...
      FROM regions, ...
     WHERE ...
```

This SP is used all over the place - in places where it will return tens of regions and in places where it will return tens of thousands.

I also have a function, `GetRegionPath` which gets the "path" of a region.  It's a moderately expensive function - there's no problem running it on tens of regions, but on tens of thousands would be unacceptable.

I need to write a stored procedure, `GetRegionsWithPaths`, that gets regions with *exactly the same logic, now and forever* as `GetRegions`, but which includes the path of a region in the result set.

At the moment, `GetRegionsWithPaths` is an exact copy of `GetRegions`, with the addition of the path:

```
OPEN out_cur FOR
    SELECT id, name, ..., GetRegionPath(id) path
      FROM regions, ...
     WHERE ...
```

but that's not acceptable - if someone edits `GetRegions` then the two SPs will be out of sync.  What I'd like is to take the cursor from `GetRegions` and then add the path to it.  Something like:

```
GetRegions(..., v_cur);

OPEN out_cur FOR
    SELECT id, name, ..., GetRegionPath(id) path
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM v_cur );
```

Is this possible?  If so, what's the syntax?

Comment: I would add an extra parameter to the GetRegions SP called "includedPath" (0-No, 1-Yes). The SP would ALWAYS return the "Path" column but if the parameter was "0" it would be NULL. Then add an extra column to your cursor to call "GetPath" like this "CASE WHEN includePath = 1 THEN GetRegionPath(id) ELSE NULL END CASE".

Comment: @MarcoPolo  that's a really good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: You may even dynamically based on the parameter open two different cursors, one with the column and the other without it.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I'm not sure how that helps me - I need the logic to be the same, so I'd still need to read from the first cursor to write to the second.

Comment: Added the implementation with the parameter as proposed by @Maco

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (that could eventually be simplified) is to use a table function to process the cursor and to add the function value.

Assume the function returning the sys_refcursor is called `get_cur` and that the cursor consist of column `ID, NAME` (this is important, as the table function requires type definition).

You declare the TYPE for the row (including the additional path column) and for the resulting table.

```
create type t_row is object
 ( id             number(10),
   name varchar2(10),
   path varchar2(10)
);
/

create type t_rows is table of t_row;
/
```

and define the table function fetching the cursor and adding the function call.

```
create or replace function get_cur2  return 
t_rows
PIPELINED
as
   cv_out     sys_refcursor;
   id   number;
   name   varchar2(100);    
begin
      cv_out := get_cur; 
      loop 
        FETCH cv_out INTO id, name;
        exit when cv_out%NOTFOUND;
        pipe row(t_row(id,name, GetRegionPath(id)));
      end loop;
      close    cv_out;
      return;
end;
/
```

Now you may select the data from the table function

```
select * from  table(get_cur2); 

        ID NAME       PATH     
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 one        path 1     
         2 two        path 2
```

and of course you may use this query to open a cursor in a third function that will return the SYS_REFCURSOR with the additional path column.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way of doing it that doesn't require me to know the row type of the first cursor?

Comment: @Simon table function requires a strong type definition, but check the alternative in the second answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation using the parameter proposed in the comments.

Suppose the original function looks like this

```
create or replace function get_cur return SYS_REFCURSOR is
cv_out     sys_refcursor;
begin
 OPEN cv_out  
      FOR 
      select   Id,   name from tab;
 return cv_out;
end;
/
```

You add a parameter `return_path` which is either 0 - which returns the original cursor or 1 - which will return the original curosr with the path column.

The implementation could be like this

```
create or replace function get_cur_with_param(return_path NUMBER) return SYS_REFCURSOR is
cv_out     sys_refcursor;
v_stmt_str      VARCHAR2(4000);
begin
 v_stmt_str := 'select   Id,   name '||case when return_path = 1 then ', GetRegionPath(id)' end ||' from tab';
 OPEN cv_out  FOR v_stmt_str; 
 return cv_out;
end;
/
```

than `get_cur_with_param(0)` returns the 2 column cursor and `get_cur_with_param(1)` returns the cursor with the `path` column added.

Note that the SQL is build dynamically, but will end only with two variants, so this will be no problem for parsing. If you have additional parameters in the query use bind variables adding the USING clause.